# Get return value from User Account Control dialog box

Tags: c++, c, windows, user-accounts

I'm not sure if it is possible but if it is then i'd want to know how. Using ShellExecute() allows one to execute commands and open stuff so I decided to open `cmd.exe` as administrator with this small piece of code.

```
ShellExecute(0, "runas", "cmd.exe", command, 0, SW_HIDE);    // command being a cmd line command
// now it works okay, it runs cmd as administrator, i want to get the return value
// of the UAC 'yes' or 'no' option.ie.
// in pseudo code
if( UAC == NO ) // do something
else // do something else
```

Is it possible to code up something like that using C/C++?

Comment: Better to use ShellExecuteEx, I think, since that gives you more information about the created process.  I think you'll get an error code if the user rejects the elevation prompt.